# Is there an algorithm to find a linear dependence between points on elliptic curves?

Tags: algorithms, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ of characteristic $p$. Let $P,Q\in E(\mathbb{F}_q)$, such that $Q=mP+n\tau(P)$, where $\tau$ is the p-th power of frobenious map and $m$ and $n$ are integers.
It is clear that the problem of finding $m$ and $n$ from $Q$ and $P$ must be at least as hard as the discrete logarithm problem. I am looking for some algorithm which can solve this kind of problems.
Is there an algorithm for general cases, for example when we have three points $Q,P_1,P_2\in E(\mathbb{F}_q)$ such that $Q=mP_1+nP_2$ (number of points can be more than 3).

Comment: If you choose known multiples of $P$, $P_i$, won't this be exactly the discrete logarithm for $Q$ unknown multiple of $P$?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand. In my example $P$ and $\tau(P)$ are independent. Could you explain for me, please?

Comment: Suppose given $P,Q$, you want to solve DL $Q=x P$. Give three points $P_1=2P,P_2=10P,P_3=100P$. If you can solve $Q=a_1 P_1 + a_2 P_2 + a_3 P_3$, then $Q= (2a_1+10 a_2 + 100 a_3)P$ modulo the order.

Comment: Why does $\tau(Q)$ lie on $E$? You either want $E$ to be defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$ or $\tau$ to be the $q$-th power Frobenius.

Comment: Ok I think I get your point Joro! You mean if I can find such relation, I can solve ECDLP. is is true?

Comment: You are right Rene, In my example the curve is defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$. I should correct it, thank you.

Comment: Yes, you can solve ECDLP this way. And if you can solve it, you can solve your problem too.

Comment: OK! Finally, I get the point. In your example $P_1$ and $P_2$ are depended. But what will happen in the independent points?  I think In these cases, solving DLP does not solve the problem. Is it true?

Comment: Answered. If the group order is prime, they can't be independent. They can be independent if the "generators" are not unique, in which case try all generators. Gave reference.

Answer (score 0):

Answering because of too many comments.

If you can solve ECDLP, you can solve your problem
and the converse holds too.

The simplest cases is if the group order $r$ is prime.

Then all points are of maximal order $r$.

Choose a point $G$ and solve ECDLP $P_i=g_i G$
and $Q=q G$.

Then you must solve $q = \sum x_i g_i \mod{r}$, for $x_i$, which is easy.

For the converse, set $P_i = i G$. Solving $ Q= a_1 P_1 + ... a_n P_n$
solves the discrete logarithm $Q= x P \implies x= \sum (a_i i) \mod{r}$.

In the case when $r$ is not prime, the only problem is if
the "generator" is not unique. In this case, try all "generators",
e.g. see this:  https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/voloch/Preprints/EC-Generators.pdf

Comment: Suppose that $E$ has two generators $G_1$ and $G_2$, then every $P_i$ is of the form $P_i=x_i G_1+y_i G_2$. You mean having an Oracle to solve ECDLP, we can find $x_i$ and $y_i$? I can't do that!